# Continuous extensions for an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a countable subset of $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$. Suppose that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $y\in c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\langle y,x_n\rangle|\leq C\|y\|_{\infty},\qquad(1)
$$
Now could we prove (1) holds for all $y\in c_0(\mathbb{N})$?

For definition of $c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$, see [$c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#c,_c0_and_c00). Note that $c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ is dense in $c_0(\mathbb{N})$.

---

My attempt: For any $y\in c_0(\mathbb{N})$, there exists a coutable subset $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in $c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\|y_k-y\|_\infty\to0$. Notice that for each $n$, we have
$$
|\langle y,x_n\rangle|=\lim_{k\to\infty}|\langle y_k,x_n\rangle|
$$
and hence
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\langle y,x_n\rangle|=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}|\langle y_k,x_n\rangle|\qquad(2)
$$
If we are allowed to swap the limit of RHS in (2), then with (1) we have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\langle y_k,x_n\rangle|\leq C\lim_{k\to\infty}\|y_k\|_\infty=C\|y\|_\infty
$$
which is the desired result. Now the concern is whether we can swap the limit in (2). Or any additional condition needed for $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to make the swap valid?

---

Update: Thanks for the counter example from Gred! If we impose the condition that for any $1<s\leq2$, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded in $\ell_s(\mathbb{N})$, will the result be true? In fact, the problem is from a paper and the authour aims to show $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$. So we can not assume $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: You know that this result holds true or you might be looking for a counter example?

Comment: @Falcon I summarized this problem from a paper. The author only said "by continous extension" but I thought there was some gap. I am not quite sure about this result is true or not.

Comment: If you replace $\limsup $ in $(1)$ by $\sup$ the conclusion holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt: Let $x_n=n^2 e_n$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$. If $y \in c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\langle y,x_n\rangle|=0$ (hence you can choose any $C>0$) but for $y=(1/k)$ we get
$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty}|\langle y,x_n\rangle| = \infty.
$$
I think that if $(x_n)$ is bounded then the inequality extends to $c_{0}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: @Bruno B, not necessarily. The sequence $(0,.., 0, n^2, 0, ... )$ is in $\ell^1$ and unbounded in $\ell^\infty$

Comment: @BrunoB $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $l^1$, that is each $x_n \in l^1$. That does not mean that this sequence is bounded.

Comment: I realized my mistake right after pressing send, yeah

Comment: Also by taking $x_n := n^3e_n$ then we can't even extend the inequality to $y \in \ell^1$ since $y = (1/n^2)_n$ would be a counterexample for the same reason, so it does look like you need more conditions on $(x_n)_n$ for any chance of going out of $c_{00}$ indeed...

Answer (score 3):

Boundedness in every $\ell^s$ for $s>1$ does not help. Let $$x_n(k)=\begin{cases} 0 & k\le n \\ {1\over k-n} & n<k\le 2n\\ 0 & k>2n \end{cases}$$ Then $x_n$ is bounded in $\ell^s$ for every $s>1,$ but not in $\ell^1.$ Indeed
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_n(k)^s=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^s}\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^s},\quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_n(k)=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k} $$
Moreover
$$\limsup |\langle y,x_n\rangle |=0,\qquad y\in c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$$